# How can I use Parse Push to send a push notifications from a change in my SQL Server Database?

Tags: android, ios, sql-server, parse-platform, push-notification

I have a database in SQL Server and I want to use Parse Push to send a push notification to devices using an iOS app when a change in the SQL Server database occurs. Any ideas on how to do this with Parse Push or any other service??

Comment: How would your app know that something is changed in db  ?

Comment: Thats why I want a push notifications sent to the app because lets say someone commented on something you posted, that comment is going to be put up on the database and the database will trigger a procedure to send a push notification to the phone that pertains to the user who has received the comment notifying him that someone commented on his post. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: AFAIK databases never interact with the server